# C# Kinect for Windows: How to combining/overlaying the skeleton and color stream/image?

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

i'm trying to code a programm that shows me the current colorstream and overlays/combines it with the skeleton stream.

i took the microsoft skeletonviewer example and tried to implement the colorstream. Well that worked, the colorstream is running, but the skeleton disappeared...

So now my question for you: How can i enable the skeleton so that if person stands right in front of the kinect, the colorstream and the skeleton appears?

here's my code:

```
namespace Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.SkeletonBasics
{
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using Microsoft.Kinect;
using System;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Width of output drawing
    /// </summary>
    private const float RenderWidth = 640.0f;

    /// <summary>
    /// Height of our output drawing
    /// </summary>
    private const float RenderHeight = 480.0f;

    /// <summary>
    /// Thickness of drawn joint lines
    /// </summary>
    private const double JointThickness = 3;

    /// <summary>
    /// Thickness of body center ellipse
    /// </summary>
    private const double BodyCenterThickness = 10;

    /// <summary>
    /// Thickness of clip edge rectangles
    /// </summary>
    private const double ClipBoundsThickness = 10;

    /// <summary>
    /// Brush used to draw skeleton center point
    /// </summary>
    private readonly Brush centerPointBrush = Brushes.Blue;

    /// <summary>
    /// Brush used for drawing joints that are currently tracked
    /// </summary>
    private readonly Brush trackedJointBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 68, 192, 68));

    /// <summary>
    /// Brush used for drawing joints that are currently inferred
    /// </summary>        
    private readonly Brush inferredJointBrush = Brushes.Yellow;

    /// <summary>
    /// Pen used for drawing bones that are currently tracked
    /// </summary>
    private readonly Pen trackedBonePen = new Pen(Brushes.Green, 6);

    /// <summary>
    /// Pen used for drawing bones that are currently inferred
    /// </summary>        
    private readonly Pen inferredBonePen = new Pen(Brushes.Gray, 1);

    /// <summary>
    /// Active Kinect sensor
    /// </summary>
    //private KinectSensor sensor;
    KinectSensor sensor = KinectSensor.KinectSensors[0];
    private byte[] colorPixelData;
    private WriteableBitmap outputImage;


    /// <summary>
    /// Drawing group for skeleton rendering output
    /// </summary>
    private DrawingGroup drawingGroup;

    /// <summary>
    /// Drawing image that we will display
    /// </summary>
    private DrawingImage imageSource;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the MainWindow class.
    /// </summary>
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Draws indicators to show which edges are clipping skeleton data
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="skeleton">skeleton to draw clipping information for</param>
    /// <param name="drawingContext">drawing context to draw to</param>
    private static void RenderClippedEdges(Skeleton skeleton, DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        if (skeleton.ClippedEdges.HasFlag(FrameEdges.Bottom))
        {
            drawingContext.DrawRectangle(
                Brushes.Red,
                null,
                new Rect(0, RenderHeight - ClipBoundsThickness, RenderWidth, ClipBoundsThickness));
        }

        if (skeleton.ClippedEdges.HasFlag(FrameEdges.Top))
        {
            drawingContext.DrawRectangle(
                Brushes.Red,
                null,
                new Rect(0, 0, RenderWidth, ClipBoundsThickness));
        }

        if (skeleton.ClippedEdges.HasFlag(FrameEdges.Left))
        {
            drawingContext.DrawRectangle(
                Brushes.Red,
                null,
                new Rect(0, 0, ClipBoundsThickness, RenderHeight));
        }

        if (skeleton.ClippedEdges.HasFlag(FrameEdges.Right))
        {
            drawingContext.DrawRectangle(
                Brushes.Red,
                null,
                new Rect(RenderWidth - ClipBoundsThickness, 0, ClipBoundsThickness, RenderHeight));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Execute startup tasks
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">object sending the event</param>
    /// <param name="e">event arguments</param>
    private void WindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create the drawing group we'll use for drawing
        this.drawingGroup = new DrawingGroup();

        // Create an image source that we can use in our image control
        this.imageSource = new DrawingImage(this.drawingGroup);

        // Display the drawing using our image control
        videoimage.Source = this.imageSource;

        // Look through all sensors and start the first connected one.
        // This requires that a Kinect is connected at the time of app startup.
        // To make your app robust against plug/unplug, 
        // it is recommended to use KinectSensorChooser provided in Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit
        foreach (var potentialSensor in KinectSensor.KinectSensors)
        {
            if (potentialSensor.Status == KinectStatus.Connected)
            {
                this.sensor = potentialSensor;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (null != this.sensor)
        {
            // Turn on the skeleton stream to receive skeleton frames
            this.sensor.SkeletonStream.Enable();
            this.sensor.ColorStream.Enable(ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30);
            this.sensor.ColorFrameReady += new EventHandler<ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs>(this.SensorColorFrameReady);


            // Add an event handler to be called whenever there is new color frame data
            this.sensor.SkeletonFrameReady += this.SensorSkeletonFrameReady;


            // Start the sensor!
            try
            {
                this.sensor.Start();
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                this.sensor = null;
            }
        }

        if (null == this.sensor)
        {
            this.statusBarText.Text = Properties.Resources.NoKinectReady;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Execute shutdown tasks
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">object sending the event</param>
    /// <param name="e">event arguments</param>
    private void WindowClosing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (null != this.sensor)
        {
            this.sensor.Stop();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Event handler for Kinect sensor's SkeletonFrameReady event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">object sending the event</param>
    /// <param name="e">event arguments</param>
    private void SensorSkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        Skeleton[] skeletons = new Skeleton[0];

        using (SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
        {
            if (skeletonFrame != null)
            {
                skeletons = new Skeleton[skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength];
                skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(skeletons);
            }
        }

        using (DrawingContext dc = this.drawingGroup.Open())
        {
            // Draw a transparent background to set the render size
            //dc.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Black, null, new Rect(0.0, 0.0, RenderWidth, RenderHeight));

            if (skeletons.Length != 0)
            {
                foreach (Skeleton skel in skeletons)
                {
                    RenderClippedEdges(skel, dc);

                    if (skel.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
                    {
                        this.DrawBonesAndJoints(skel, dc);
                    }
                    else if (skel.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.PositionOnly)
                    {
                        dc.DrawEllipse(
                        this.centerPointBrush,
                        null,
                        this.SkeletonPointToScreen(skel.Position),
                        BodyCenterThickness,
                        BodyCenterThickness);
                    }
                }
            }

            // prevent drawing outside of our render area
            this.drawingGroup.ClipGeometry = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0.0, 0.0, RenderWidth, RenderHeight));
        }
    }

    private void SensorColorFrameReady(object sender, ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        using (ColorImageFrame colorFrame = e.OpenColorImageFrame())
        {
            if (colorFrame != null)
            {
                this.colorPixelData = new byte[colorFrame.PixelDataLength];

                colorFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(this.colorPixelData);

                this.outputImage = new WriteableBitmap(colorFrame.Width, colorFrame.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null);
                this.outputImage.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, colorFrame.Width, colorFrame.Height), this.colorPixelData, colorFrame.Width * 4, 0);
                this.videoimage.Source = this.outputImage;

            }
        }

     }

    /// <summary>
    /// Draws a skeleton's bones and joints
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="skeleton">skeleton to draw</param>
    /// <param name="drawingContext">drawing context to draw to</param>
    private void DrawBonesAndJoints(Skeleton skeleton, DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        // Render Torso
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.Head, JointType.ShoulderCenter);
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ShoulderCenter, JointType.ShoulderLeft);
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ShoulderCenter, JointType.ShoulderRight);
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ShoulderCenter, JointType.Spine);
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.Spine, JointType.HipCenter);
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.HipCenter, JointType.HipLeft);
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.HipCenter, JointType.HipRight);

        // Left Arm
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ShoulderLeft, JointType.ElbowLeft);
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ElbowLeft, JointType.WristLeft);
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.WristLeft, JointType.HandLeft);

        // Right Arm
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ShoulderRight, JointType.ElbowRight);
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ElbowRight, JointType.WristRight);
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.WristRight, JointType.HandRight);

        // Left Leg
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.HipLeft, JointType.KneeLeft);
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.KneeLeft, JointType.AnkleLeft);
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.AnkleLeft, JointType.FootLeft);

        // Right Leg
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.HipRight, JointType.KneeRight);
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.KneeRight, JointType.AnkleRight);
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.AnkleRight, JointType.FootRight);

        // Render Joints
        foreach (Joint joint in skeleton.Joints)
        {
            Brush drawBrush = null;

            if (joint.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked)
            {
                drawBrush = this.trackedJointBrush;                    
            }
            else if (joint.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Inferred)
            {
                drawBrush = this.inferredJointBrush;                    
            }

            if (drawBrush != null)
            {
                drawingContext.DrawEllipse(drawBrush, null, this.SkeletonPointToScreen(joint.Position), JointThickness, JointThickness);
            }

    }


    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Maps a SkeletonPoint to lie within our render space and converts to Point
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="skelpoint">point to map</param>
    /// <returns>mapped point</returns>
    private Point SkeletonPointToScreen(SkeletonPoint skelpoint)
    {
        // Convert point to depth space.  
        // We are not using depth directly, but we do want the points in our 640x480 output resolution.
        DepthImagePoint depthPoint = this.sensor.CoordinateMapper.MapSkeletonPointToDepthPoint(skelpoint, DepthImageFormat.Resolution640x480Fps30);
        return new Point(depthPoint.X, depthPoint.Y);
    }

    private Point UpdateDraw(Joint joint)
    {
        //foreach (Joint joint in skeleton.Joints)
        //{
            ColorImagePoint colorPoint = this.sensor.CoordinateMapper.MapSkeletonPointToColorPoint(joint.Position, ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30);
            //var point = new Point((int)ColorImagePoint.X / 640.0 * this.ActualWidth, (int)ColorImagePoint.Y / 480.0 * this.ActualHeight);
            return new Point(colorPoint.X, colorPoint.Y);
        //}

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Draws a bone line between two joints
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="skeleton">skeleton to draw bones from</param>
    /// <param name="drawingContext">drawing context to draw to</param>
    /// <param name="jointType0">joint to start drawing from</param>
    /// <param name="jointType1">joint to end drawing at</param>
    private void DrawBone(Skeleton skeleton, DrawingContext drawingContext, JointType jointType0, JointType jointType1)
    {
        Joint joint0 = skeleton.Joints[jointType0];
        Joint joint1 = skeleton.Joints[jointType1];

        // If we can't find either of these joints, exit
        if (joint0.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.NotTracked ||
            joint1.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.NotTracked)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Don't draw if both points are inferred
        if (joint0.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Inferred &&
            joint1.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Inferred)
        {
            return;
        }

        // We assume all drawn bones are inferred unless BOTH joints are tracked
        Pen drawPen = this.inferredBonePen;
        if (joint0.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked && joint1.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked)
        {
            drawPen = this.trackedBonePen;
        }

        drawingContext.DrawLine(drawPen, this.SkeletonPointToScreen(joint0.Position), this.SkeletonPointToScreen(joint1.Position));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the checking or unchecking of the seated mode combo box
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">object sending the event</param>
    /// <param name="e">event arguments</param>
    private void CheckBoxSeatedModeChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (null != this.sensor)
        {
            if (this.checkBoxSeatedMode.IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault())
            {
                this.sensor.SkeletonStream.TrackingMode = SkeletonTrackingMode.Seated;
            }
            else
            {
                this.sensor.SkeletonStream.TrackingMode = SkeletonTrackingMode.Default;
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            sensor.ElevationAngle = sensor.ElevationAngle - 5;
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException outOfRangeException)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(outOfRangeException.Message);
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Die niedrigste Einstellung ist bereits erreicht.", "Ungütliger Winkel");
        }
    }

    private void btnUp(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            sensor.ElevationAngle = sensor.ElevationAngle + 5;
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException outOfRangeException)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(outOfRangeException.Message);
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Die höchste Einstellung ist bereits erreicht.", "Ungütliger Winkel");
        }
    }
}
}
```

THIS IS MY XML FILE:

```
<Window x:Class="Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.SkeletonBasics.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="SkeletonApp - Kinect configuration" Height="720.075" Width="770" Loaded="WindowLoaded" Closing="WindowClosing" WindowStyle="ToolWindow">

<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MediumGreyBrush" Color="#ff6e6e6e"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="KinectPurpleBrush" Color="#ff52318f"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="KinectBlueBrush" Color="#ff00BCF2"/>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" x:Key="SquareCheckBox" >
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                    <Grid>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Transparent">
                            <Grid x:Name="SquareCheckBoxChecked">
                                <Image x:Name="CheckedNormal" Source="Images\CheckedNormal.png" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <Image x:Name="CheckedHover" Source="Images\CheckedHover.png" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid x:Name="SquareCheckBoxUnchecked" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                <Image x:Name="UncheckedNormal" Source="Images\UncheckedNormal.png" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <Image x:Name="UncheckedHover" Source="Images\UncheckedHover.png" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="SquareCheckBoxText" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" TextAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="{StaticResource KinectPurpleBrush}" FontSize="15"  Margin="9,0,0,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="SquareCheckBoxChecked"/>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="SquareCheckBoxUnchecked"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="CheckedNormal"/>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="UncheckedNormal"/>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="CheckedHover"/>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="UncheckedHover"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource KinectBlueBrush}" TargetName="SquareCheckBoxText"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Background>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF272727"/>
</Window.Background>

<Grid Name="layoutGrid" Margin="10 0 10 0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="289*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="276*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="177*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DockPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="0 0 0 20" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
    <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <Grid ClipToBounds="True">
            <Image Name="videoimage" Width="640" Height="480"/>
            <Canvas Background="Transparent" Name="ColorImagePoint"></Canvas>
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
    <CheckBox Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource SquareCheckBox}" Content="Seated Mode" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,157,10" Name="checkBoxSeatedMode" Checked="CheckBoxSeatedModeChanged" Unchecked="CheckBoxSeatedModeChanged" Foreground="White"/>
    <StatusBar Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="statusBar" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="White" Foreground="{StaticResource MediumGreyBrush}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <StatusBarItem Padding="0 0 0 10">
            <StatusBarItem.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF272727"/>
            </StatusBarItem.Background>
            <TextBlock Name="statusBarText" Margin="-1 0 0 0" Foreground="White">Click 'Seated' to change skeletal mode</TextBlock>
        </StatusBarItem>
    </StatusBar>
    <Button Content="UP" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="198,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115" Height="35" Click="btnUp" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.122,0.716" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Foreground="White" BorderBrush="DodgerBlue" Background="DodgerBlue"/>
    <Button Content="DOWN" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,5,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115" Height="35" Grid.Column="2" Click="btnDown" Grid.Row="2" Foreground="White" Background="DodgerBlue" BorderBrush="DodgerBlue"/>
    <Label x:Name="Label_Angle" Content="Adjust Kinect Angle:" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="73,10,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.787,-0.551" Background="#00000000" Foreground="White"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Is this a WPF app? What does the XAML file look like? Maybe the color stream control is just over the top of the skeleton so its just being hidden?

Comment: jep WPF, i added the XAML code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use two image controls on top of each other.  Make sure the skeleton is on top. It looks like your code currently has both the skeleton and the color image writing to "videoimage", which is why it keeps getting written over.