# Kinect SDK 2.0, Mapping skeleton to Image Overlay?

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2013, kinect

Basically I have an camera stream and i'm trying to overlay a Skeleton on top of the Camera Stream, I can successfully to do this how the skeleton isn't mapped on top of the stream correctly.

I have tried using the Coordinate mapper and changing the depth space point to a ColorSpacePoint however this makes the skeleton completely disappear.

```
      #region Handling the body frame data arriving from the Sensor for Skeleton
    /// Handles the body frame data arriving from the sensor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">object sending the event</param>
    /// <param name="e">event arguments</param>
    private void Reader_FrameArrived(object sender, BodyFrameArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Normal Boolean
        bool dataReceived = false;

        //Using = Provides a convenient syntax that ensures the correct use of IDisposable objects.
        using (BodyFrame bodyFrame = e.FrameReference.AcquireFrame())
        {
            //If from is not Null
            if (bodyFrame != null)
            {
                //If body is not null
                if (this.bodies == null)
                {
                    //New body in array number of bodies
                    this.bodies = new Body[bodyFrame.BodyCount];
                }

                // The first time GetAndRefreshBodyData is called, Kinect will allocate each Body in the array.
                // As long as those body objects are not disposed and not set to null in the array,
                // those body objects will be re-used.
                bodyFrame.GetAndRefreshBodyData(this.bodies);
                dataReceived = true;
            }
        }

        //if Data has been recieved
        if (dataReceived)
        {
            //Use Drawing Group
            using (DrawingContext dc = this.drawingGroup.Open())
            {
                // Draw a transparent background to set the render size
                dc.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Transparent, null, new Rect(0.0, 0.0, this.displayWidth, this.displayHeight));

                //Set the index of the Pen to 0
                int penIndex = 0;

                //For each body
                foreach (Body body in this.bodies)
                {
                    //This is the colour of the Pen, It goes in array order for each body.
                    Pen drawPen = this.bodyColors[penIndex++];

                    //If body is tracked
                    if (body.IsTracked)
                    {
                        this.DrawClippedEdges(body, dc);

                        IReadOnlyDictionary<JointType, Joint> joints = body.Joints;

                        // convert the joint points to depth (display) space
                        Dictionary<JointType, Point> jointPoints = new Dictionary<JointType, Point>();




                        foreach (JointType jointType in joints.Keys)
                        {


                                // sometimes the depth(Z) of an inferred joint may show as negative
                                // clamp down to 0.1f to prevent coordinatemapper from returning (-Infinity, -Infinity)
                                CameraSpacePoint SkeletonPosition = joints[jointType].Position;

                                if (SkeletonPosition.Z < 0)
                                {
                                    SkeletonPosition.Z = InferredZPositionClamp;
                                }

                                ColorSpacePoint colorSpacePoint = this.coordinateMapper.MapCameraPointToColorSpace(SkeletonPosition);
                                jointPoints[jointType] = new Point(colorSpacePoint.X / 3.75, colorSpacePoint.Y / 3.75); //Divide Positions by 3.8 to correctly map skeleton to canvas

                        }



                        //Draw the bodies with the Pen Colour selected on amount of bodies available
                        this.DrawBody(joints, jointPoints, dc, drawPen);

                        //Draw the Left Hand, Feeding in the State and type of Joint
                        this.DrawHand(body.HandLeftState, jointPoints[JointType.HandLeft], dc);

                        //Draw the right Hand, Feeding in the state and type of Joint
                        this.DrawHand(body.HandRightState, jointPoints[JointType.HandRight], dc);

                        this.test(joints, jointPoints, dc, drawPen, ElbowAngle);
                    }
                }

                // prevent drawing outside of our render area
                this.drawingGroup.ClipGeometry = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0.0, 0.0, this.displayWidth, this.displayHeight));
            }
        }
```

As you can see im trying to use ColorSpacePoint to map the joints to the colour stream correctly but for some reason it does not work, can someone kindly explain what im doing wrong?

Here is what my XAML Looks like:

```
 <Window x:Class="MedicalKinectWPF.FreeFormSkeleton"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:k="http://schemas.microsoft.com/kinect/2014"
        WindowState="Maximized"
        Loaded="FreeFormSkeletonWindow_Loaded"
        Closing="FreeFormSkeletonWindow_Closing"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="1920" Width="1080" Background="#FF381E1E">

    <Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MediumGreyBrush" Color="#ff6e6e6e" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="KinectPurpleBrush" Color="#ff52318f" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="KinectBlueBrush" Color="#ff00BCF2" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="120px" />
            <RowDefinition Height="2" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="2" />
            <RowDefinition Height="100px" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Free Form Skeleton Title Label (HEADER)-->
        <Label x:Name="Title"  Content = "Free Form Skeleton Demonstration" TextElement.Foreground="Snow" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                   Margin="318,10,247,0" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                   Height="44" Width="427" 
                   FontSize="25"  FontWeight="Bold"/>

           <!-- Seperator -->
           <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Fill="LightBlue" />
          <!-- Kinect Output-->
          <Grid Grid.Row="2">
            <Grid x:Name="CameraSkeletonGrid">

                <!-- Camera image -->
                <Image x:Name="CameraImage" Width="1920" Height="1080" />

                <!--Skeleton Image-->
                <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Stretch="UniformToFill"  Width="1920" Height="1080" />
            </Grid>

            <!-- Skeletal Tracking Only -->
            <Grid x:Name="Skeleton" Margin="20" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <Viewbox>
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Stretch="UniformToFill" Width="1920" Height="1080"/> 
                </Viewbox>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
          <!-- Seperator -->
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Fill="AliceBlue" />
 <!-- Navigation -->
 <Grid Grid.Row="4">
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <ColumnDefinition />
   <ColumnDefinition />
   <ColumnDefinition />
 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <!-- Switch to camera & body -->
            <Button x:Name = "ToggleRGBSkeleton"  FontSize="25" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" TextElement.Foreground="Snow"  Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="White" Click="OnToggleCamera" Cursor="Hand" >
                <TextBlock Text="RGB Camera With &#xA; Skeleton Overlay"/> 
                 </Button>  
            <!-- Switch to Skeleton Only Mode -->
            <Button x:Name="ToggleSkeleton"  Grid.Column="1" FontSize="25"     FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" TextElement.Foreground="Snow"  Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="White"  Click="OnToggleSkeleton" Cursor="Hand">
                <TextBlock Text="Skeleton Only"/>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>``
```

More information is available if you, thanks in advance

Comment: What does your XAML look like? Part of the issue could be that the visual elements are not lined up

Comment: Give me 5 minutes and I will edit the post, and put my Xaml coding in for you.

Comment: in the mean time this link might help: http://pterneas.com/2014/05/06/understanding-kinect-coordinate-mapping/

Comment: Xaml Posted and i've taken a look at that multiple times I can't see what im doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I see that you are using a separate `Image` for your camera and your skeleton; I utilize a `DrawingGroup` to get the skeleton and the camera to line up. Also, I don't typically rely on `Grid`s to place my `Image`s - I place everything on a `Canvas` or if you really need a `Grid`, put both `Image`s in the same cell of the `Grid`.

Please look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515932/c-sharp-kinect-for-windows-how-to-combining-overlaying-the-skeleton-and-color-s) for an example using the `DrawingGroup`.

Comment: How would I put both images on the same cell of the grid?